# GCP PubSub to BigQuery - Anybody Have It Working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, publish-subscribe

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot get PubSub Subscription to BigQuery sink to work using directions such as https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery.

- Created a topic that has a Service Account SA
- Created a dataset and a couple of tables that are shared at the dataset level to SA
- Created a subscription with multiple configs that match the table schemas
- Added IAM permissions for the SA (BQ Editor, Metadata Viewer)

After manually-publishing messages, I expected them to appear in the created BigQuery tables OR at least an error message indicating a problem.

However, all topics and subscriptions are in the green state and there are no log messages, and there is no data in the tables (using BQ details screen or "select * from dataset.table") after submitting messages manually, even after waiting. [We tried everything in the troubleshooting page: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery-troubleshooting].

Any ideas?

Best,

Jon

Comment: Did you try to query your database? (not a preview, a real query, select * from ....)

Comment: Definitely did: SELECT * FROM ds.table

Comment: usual spots checks i've done are check 1) auto-expiration on table in bq, 2) also you may enable "Enable ACK messages" in the pubsub subscription as debugging step. 3) check job history from bq console for errors in delivery. hope these spot checks helps you

Answer (score 0):

As @Bihag Kashikar mentioned in the comments, the possible solution is to do usual spot checks:

First is to **check the auto-expiration** on the table in BigQuery. Second, enable the **"Enable ACK messages"** in the Pub/Sub subscription as a debugging step. Last is to **check job history** from the BigQuery console for errors in delivery.

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is the only possible workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input @Paola.

No auto-expiration on BQ table, we did create another parallel PULL subscription to allow the PULL from PubSub to work, which confirms the messages are getting published. Job History and logs are clean with the exception of a retry error:

An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 5034996

It turns out that the problem was that billing was not enabled. Once a billing account was attached it worked right away. I believe I suggested to google in the bug that they note that this feature will only work with billing applied.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you do not have a connected billing account you cannot use this feature. Once a billing account was connected, it worked easily the first time.

I asked Google to add a note stating such in their docs.

Thanks for your help!